# Napalm connection to Cisco IOS router using telnet

Tags: python-3.x, cisco-ios, napalm

I'm trying to use Napalm to connect to Cisco routers using telnet from the python chevron and getting an error from netmiko.ssh.

Here is the snippet that I am using

```
from napalm import get_network_driver

driver = get_network_driver('ios')

with driver('ip_address', 'username', 'password', optional_args={'port': 23,'transport': telnet}) as device:

    print(device.get_facts())
```

Here is the error message that I am receiving:

```
NAPALM didn't catch this exception. Please, fill a bugfix on https://github.com/napalm-automation/napalm/issues
Don't forget to include this traceback.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\napalm\base\base.py", line 46, in __enter__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\napalm\ios\ios.py", line 169, in open
    self.device = self._netmiko_open(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\napalm\base\base.py", line 86, in _netmiko_open
    self._netmiko_device = ConnectHandler(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 312, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco\cisco_ios.py", line 17, in __init__
    return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 346, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 351, in _open
    self.establish_connection()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 910, in establish_connection
    self.telnet_login()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\netmiko\cisco_base_connection.py", line 171, in telnet_login
    raise NetmikoAuthenticationException(msg)
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoAuthenticationException: Login failed: ip_address
```

Answer (score 0):

Login failed on the host with name ip_address, if 'ip_address' is the name of the host you trying to connect, maybe you can to put the host IP in place.

I believe that this short video can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTapxlSEo1E

Do you ask yourself where to put the host address?

The name of the host you are trying to connect is 'ip_address'?

The same question to the fields 'username' and 'password'.

You are near. The best for you!

Answer (score 0):

to be able to establish an SSH/Telnet-Session to an Cisco-IOS/XE-Device you need to

a) enable user-authentication at the "line"-level:

```
line vty 0 15
 login local
```

b) add a local user account with correct privilege level:

```
username testuser privilege 15 secret testpass
```

c) enable the correct protocol for incoming sessions:

```
line vty 0 15
 transport input telnet
```

telnet might be default, good idea to disable this and switch to ssh:

```
line vty 0 15
 transport input ssh
```

having done this, this works just fine:

```
>>> with driver(hostname='192.168.193.139', username='testuser', password='testpass', optional_args={'port': 23,'transport': "telnet"}) as device:
...   print(device.get_facts())

...
{'uptime': 660, 'vendor': 'Cisco', 'os_version': 'Virtual XE Software (X86_64_LINUX_IOSD-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.16.16, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)', 'serial_number': '91STKVRFLW91', 'model': 'CSR1000V', 'hostname': 'CSR-VM', 'fqdn': 'CSR-VM.lab.local', 'interface_list': ['GigabitEthernet1', 'GigabitEthernet2', 'GigabitEthernet3', 'GigabitEthernet4', 'Loopback0', 'Loopback1000']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the word telnet between quotation marks or apostrophes. The snippet below worked in my testes. Just make the following changes:

```
dev_creds = {
    'hostname': '172.16.0.3',
    'username': 'cisco',
    'password': 'cisco',
    'optional_args': {'secret': 'cisco', "port": 23, 'transport': 'telnet'}
}

device = driver(**dev_creds)
```